# Universal property of a monoid ring expressed as an adjunction?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid, adjoint-functors

Given a (not necessarily commutative) ring $R$ and a monoid $M$, we can form the monoid ring $R[M]$ in the same way as we form the group ring. I would expect the monoid ring construction to be left adjoint to some "forgetful" functor, probably sending a ring to its underlying multiplicative monoid, but the universal property given in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid_ring) suggests that it is not so simple, since it involves a pair of homomorphisms and a commutativity condition. This suggests to me that maybe it involves functors (into or out of) a coslice category (perhaps rings under R?).

What would be the correct way of stating this universal property as an adjunction? I am just curious.

Comment: I think your first idea might work if you fix the ring $R$. Compare how https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Adjoint also works with a fixed ring.

Comment: I don't know what construction you have in mind if $R$ isn't commutative. There are two things you could mean here, depending on whether or not you insist that every element of $R$ commute with every element of $M$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I believe that out of these two things the one which is adjoint to the obvious forgetful functor is the one where the elements of the monoid *do* commute with the elements of the ring, right?

Comment: If you assume they commute, as the article does, then $R[ℕ] = R[x]$, so $R[x]$ would have to be a free $R$-algebra on one generator, and in particular $UR ≅ \mathrm{Hom}(R[X], R)$. But only ring morphisms $R[x] → R$ that fix $R$ are evaluations at _central_ elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Christian Sievers](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/338756/christian-sievers)'s comment has the right idea. Fix the ring $R$. An [$R$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra) is an $R$-bimodule, $M$, equipped with a map $\times:M\otimes M\rightarrow M$ which is associative and has an identity element. Note that $R[M]$ is not just a ring but actually an $R$-algebra.

Every $R$-algebra has an underlying multiplicative monoid given by forgetting about the $R$-module structure and only remembering $\times$. The functor $R[-]$ is left adjoint to this forgetful functor.

Abelian groups are exactly the same thing as $\mathbb Z$-modules. Similarly, rings are the same as $\mathbb Z$-algebras (because their underlying additive groups are $\mathbb Z$-modules, and their multiplication gives $\times$). Therefore the left adjoint to the forgetful functor which takes any ring and gives its multiplicative monoid is the functor $\mathbb Z[-]$.

Comment: Are you assuming that $R$ is commutative here? If not, there's subtlety hiding in your use of the term "bilinear." For $M$ a left $R$-module you might want a bilinear map $\mu : M \times M \to M$ to mean a map which is $R$-linear in each variable separately. But actually this forces $\mu(ra, sb) = rs \mu(a, b) = sr \mu(a, b)$; in other words, the action of $R$ on $M$ is forced to factor through its abelianization.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Good point! I was actually thinking of $M$ as a bimodule, but it doesn't really matter, because as you say the action of $R$ has to factor through its abeilianisation, so (in this case) a left module is a bimodule is a right module.

Comment: If $R$ is not commutative this still doesn't work. The ring of polynomials is a special case of monoid ring, but it's not a free $R$-algebra. On the other hand, for $R$ commutative, you'll need to change the definition of algebra back to the one with $R$-module, because this one is more general. (It's equivalent to a morphism $R → S$, while the usual one is $R → Z(S)$)

Comment: What if we want to fix $M$ here, and consider the endofunctor $R\mapsto R[M]$ of CRing? My intuition is that this doesn't work so well. If it did, we might have an abstract proof of something like the Hilbert Basis Theorem.